# Use reflection to invoke a generic method

Tags: c#, xamarin, reflection

I have a string variable in my code, and I need to use it to invoke a generic method in a Xamarin form project for page navigation.

My initial code.

```
 string currentPage = SelectedFunction.PageName;
 var abc1 = Type.GetType(currentPage);
 CoreMethods.SwitchSelectedTab<abc>();
```

But after doing some research and talking with some people, I understand we cannot initialise a generic method this way, as the Type need to set at compile time. After some further research, I learned we could achieve this using reflection API. And I gave it a try.

This is my current version of code.

```
var currentPage = SelectedFunction.PageModelName;
var abc1 = Type.GetType(currentPage);
MethodInfo method = typeof(PageModelCoreMethods).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("SwitchSelectedTab");

        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(abc1);
generic.Invoke(new PageModelCoreMethods(CurrentPage, this), null);
```

The code compiles correctly but the navigation does not happen.

Some further info on the generic method that I am calling: The method is in a nuget package. Here is the github link for the class : https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/d1c9e1896e4040388ef43203df1254787bc84f36/src/FreshMvvm/PageModelCoreMethods.cs

**Edit 1**

I reviewed my code after John's suggestion. And he was right, my logic was definitely incorrect.

This is what I am trying to achieve (works when done staticly)

```
var currentPage = SelectedFunction.PageName;
var abc1 = Type.GetType(currentPage);
CoreMethods.SwitchSelectedTab<HomeViewModel>();
CoreMethods.PushPageModel<RefreshLocationItemPageModel>();
```

Previously, I was trying CoreMethods.SwitchSelectedTab();. So i edited my code to

```
var currentPage = SelectedFunction.PageName;
var abc1 = Type.GetType(currentPage);
CoreMethods.SwitchSelectedTab<HomeViewModel>();
MethodInfo method = typeof(PageModelCoreMethods).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("PushPageModel");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(abc1);
generic.Invoke(CoreMethods, null);
```

But I get an exception when i do this.

```
{System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl (System.String name, 
System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder 
binder, System.Reflection.CallingConventions callConv, System.Type[] 
types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) [0x00059] in 
<f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at System.Type.GetMethod (System.String name, 
System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) [0x0000e] in 
<f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at System.Reflection.TypeInfo.GetDeclaredMethod (System.String name) 
[0x00000] in <f32579baafc1404fa37ba3ec1abdc0bd>:0 
at
```

********.StateManager.PausedFunctionPageModel.NavigateToFunction () [0x00020] in /*****/Functions/StateManager/PausedFunctionPageModel.cs:55 
  at ******.Functions.StateManager.PausedFunctionPageModel.set_SelectedFunction (*******.Common.Models.PageState value) [0x00022] in /********/Functions/StateManager/PausedFunctionPageModel.cs:29 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in :0 }

Comment: Have you tried `generic.Invoke(CoreMethods, null)` (passing the existing instance of `CoreMethods` instead of creating a new one)?

Comment: @JohnWu: I just tried and its the same result. No error, but it just doesnt navigate. But it makes sense

Comment: If you temporarily hardcode it to work the old way (`CoreMethods.SwitchSelectedTab<abc>();`), does it still work? Could be another problem has crept in and you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @JohnWu : I have updated my question that reflects what you have said. Please check

Comment: Is it suggesting there are multiple versions of  PushPageModel()

Comment: There's more than one PushPageModel method. One of them takes one generic parameter, the other takes two. I suggest you use [GetDeclaredMethods()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.getdeclaredmethods(v=vs.110).aspx) (with an s) and iterate through the results.

Comment: Ok. I would try that

Comment: @JohnWu : Thanks a lot, I got it working.

Comment: var currentPage = SelectedFunction.PageName;
            var abc1 = Type.GetType(currentPage);
            CoreMethods.SwitchSelectedTab<HomeViewModel>();
            var methods = typeof(PageModelCoreMethods).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethods("PushPageModel").ToList();
            MethodInfo generic = methods[5].MakeGenericMethod(abc1);
            generic.Invoke(CoreMethods, new object[] { true });

Comment: More than happy to mark it as an answer, if u post it. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one PushPageModel method. One of them takes one generic parameter, the other takes two. I suggest you use [GetDeclaredMethods()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.getdeclaredmethods(v=vs.110).aspx) (with an s) and iterate through the results.